# Problems trying to zoom the page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my webpage, it goes crazy when I try to zoom :)). I made the page kinda responsive using CSS grid (it was the first time when I used that) but now I am getting very frustrated because I cannot zoom without messing up the whole page, divs, layouts, design etc :)).

You can see here what I am talking about: https://youtu.be/5zQX1qnoRX0

thank you

```css
/* basic.css */

.container>div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    2em;
}

html,
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    0px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
    background: url["imagini/123.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
}

button {
    background: none;
    color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: u rl("imagini/rama.png") 30 stretch;
    -o-border-image: u rl("imagini/rama.png") 30 stretch;
    border-image: u rl("imagini/rama.png") 70 stretch;
    15px;
    transition: .6s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255.5);
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .5s;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translateX(-130px) skewX(-15deg);
}

button:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translate(-100px) scaleX(-15deg);
}

button:hover {
    background: #B8860B;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover:before {
    transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: .6;
    transition: .7s;
}

button:hover:after {
    transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s;
}

#umbra {
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#jos {
    background-image: u rl("imagini/11.png");
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1];
    Corbel;
    14pt;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: black;
}

/* index.css */
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    /* grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 180px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px;*/
    /* grid-template-rows: 170px 30px 190x 190px 190px 190px 190px 190px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 70px;*/
    grid-template-rows: repeat(13, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "stg stg nmc1 meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu nmc2 drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "nmc5 nmc5 nmc30 jos jos jos jos jos jos nmc31 nmc7 nmc7"
}

@media screen and (max-width:1921px) {
    .banner {
        grid-area: logo;
        background-image: url["imagini/banner.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    button {
        left: 4%;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .div1 {
        18px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1681px) {
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1441px] {
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 85px;
    }
    .div1 {
        14px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1370px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        grid-gap: 3px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(13, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas: "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "stg stg nmc1 meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu nmc2 drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "nmc5 nmc5 nmc30 jos jos jos jos jos jos nmc31 nmc7 nmc7";
    }
    .banner {
        grid-area: logo;
        background-image: url["imagini/banner.png");
        background-size: 740px 145px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 84px;
    }
    .div1 {
        12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1281px) {
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 81px;
    }
    .div1 {
        11px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1153px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        grid-gap: 3px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(13, 1fr];
        grid-template-areas: "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "cap1 cap1 nmc1 logo logo logo logo logo logo nmc2 cap2 cap2" "stg stg meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu meniu drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "stg stg corp corp corp corp corp corp corp corp drp drp" "nmc5 nmc5 nmc30 jos jos jos jos jos jos nmc31 nmc7 nmc7";
    }
    .banner {
        grid-area: logo;
        background-image: url["imagini/banner.png");
        background-size: 650px 170px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 83px;
    }
    .div1 {
        9px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
    .banner {
        grid-area: logo;
        background-image: u rl("imagini/banner.png");
        background-size: 600px 160px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 82px;
    }
    .div1 {
        40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 801px) {
    .banner {
        grid-area: logo;
        background-image: u rl("imagini/banner.png");
        background-size: 460px 90px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    button {
        left: 0%;
        width: 63px;
    }
    .div1 {
        40%;
    }
}

.cap1 {
    grid-area: cap1;
    background-image: u rl("imagini/tutan.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.cap2 {
    grid-area: cap2;
    background-image: u rl("imagini/tutan.png"];
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.nimic1 {
    grid-area: nmc1;
}

.nimic2 {
    grid-area: nmc2;
}

.nimic5 {
    grid-area: nmc5;
    background-image: url["imagini/jos.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.nimic7 {
    grid-area: nmc7;
    background-image: u rl("imagini/jos.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.menu {
    grid-area: meniu;
}

.stanga {
    grid-area: stg;
    background-image: u rl("imagini/poza1.png"];
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.trup {
    grid-area: corp;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 1em/8em;
}

.dreapta {
    grid-area: drp;
    background-image: url["imagini/poza2.png"];
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.jos {
    grid-area: jos;
}

.content {
    grid-area: cap3;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: cap4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <link rel="nofollow" href="index.css">
   <link rel="nofollow" href="basic.css">
   <title>Egiptul Antic</title>
   <link rel="nofollow" href="imagini/titlephoto.ico">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="stanga"></div>
      <div class="dreapta"></div>
      <div class="trup"></div>
      <div class="cap1"></div>
      <div class="cap2"></div>
      <div class="nimic1"></div>
      <div class="nimic2"></div>
      <div class="banner" id="umbra"></div>
      <div class="nimic31"></div>
      <div class="nimic30"></div>
      <div class="menu">
         <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa1.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa1</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa2.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa2</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa3.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa3</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa4.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa4</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa5.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa5</font></button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'acasa6.html'" ><font color="#856514"; style="Corbel; 14pt;">Acasa6</font></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nimic5"></div>
      <div class="nimic7"></div>
      <div class="jos" id="jos">
         <a class="div1" href="acasa.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa1.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa1</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa2.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa2</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa3.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa3</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa4.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa4</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa5.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa5</font></a>     <font class="div1" color="#473705">|</font>     
         <a class="div1" href="acasa6.html" target="_parent"><font color="#5f4907">Acasa6</font></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what exactly is happening that you want to prevent from happening when you zoom the page and then post the relevant code, preferably embedded in the question.  Making a page not "go crazy" is not a clear objective.

Comment: I would like the site to fit each screen, and if you try my files and open the webpage you will see it works on all the screen resolutions, from 576 to 1920, but later I will write something in that box from the center, and it's kinda many things to write there and I will probably use a small font-size so people may use zoom in to read properly, and that might be a problem :)). Is it impossible to maintain the site exactly how it is now but to be able to zoom in/out like here dequeuniversity.com/library/responsive/1-non-responsive ?

Answer (score 0):

From your css, your page is not responsive, responsive means it cut across small devices like phone, medium devices and large screen devices, I will suggest you follow bootstrap breakpoints, then add yours to it starting with the smallest screen like so

> @media (min-width: 576px) { ... } // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) @media (min-width: 768px) { ... } // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) @media (min-width: 992px) { ... } // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

Then set the button sizes on each breakpoints.

Comment: But can not I make something so I could be able to zoom in and out the page without modifying the size or the aspect of the divs, because I have some problems with the banner, too. You see?

Comment: are you concern on zooming in and out of the page or rather your site to fit at each screen, whether the user is using mobile phone or large screen computer, please specify

Comment: Also rather than zooming in and out, you can actually test for responsiveness using Mozilla Firefox by going to the settings, web developer and then responsive design mode, from there you can check the behavior at different breakpoints

Comment: I would like the site to fit each screen, and if you try my files and open the webpage you will see it works on all the screen resolutions, from 576 to 1920, but later I will write something in that box from the center, and it's kinda many things to write there and I will probably use a small font-size so people may use zoom in to read properly, and that might be a problem :)). Is it impossible to maintain the site exactly how it is now but to be able to zoom in/out like here https://dequeuniversity.com/library/responsive/1-non-responsive ?

Comment: i would suggest you using a kind of pop up with jquery or bootstrap modal, since the site fits across every screen, when the user clicks any of the button, the pop up will come up with the write up in bold letters while the user is still on your page, just suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but can not I make something so I can zoom like on that website from above? without affecting those

Comment: you can but with the help of javascript, please repost the website, the one you posted contained just tutorials

Comment: https://dequeuniversity.com/library/responsive/1-non-responsive it's only about the zoom from here, not the content

Comment: ok, maybe i did not understand you very well, what i will suggest to you is rather than your users to use the browser zoom features on your page, you can actually achieve that without breaking your page using javacript

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. One more question please, what script exactly would help me here?

Comment: it all depends on the one you love most, i use jquery better, you can actually code a slider to zoom just a button text at a time without affecting your page or you could use radio button like first radio 14px, second radio 16 px and so on

Comment: or you can use this css tweak, set a hover event on your button, and then scale the button and its content to 1.2 or more, this enables your user to read the content of a button one at a time when moused over, the down side with this is the user has no control over the size of the text

Comment: I will read what you wrote here a lot of times, until I understand what you wanted to say, because I am not so good at english.. :)) I hope I will understand as soon as possible. Thanks a lot, friend!